# List<Map<String, dynamic>> - Remove duplicates but stack numbers

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm hoping someone could help me out. I'm trying to take a list of objects and stack all duplicates by retaining the same description, but increasing the quantity when required.

here is what I currently have:

test data:

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
    {'Description': 'Cheese', 'Quantity': 100, 'UoM': 'g'},
    {'Description': 'Corn', 'Quantity': 150, 'UoM': 'g'},
    {'Description': 'Cheese', 'Quantity': 52, 'UoM': 'g'},
  ];
```

The function I am trying to figure out:

```
  void stackDuplicates(items) {

    final set = Set<String>();
    int counter = 0;

    // check the entire list only once
    while (counter < items.length) {
      items.forEach((item) {

        // increase counter once a new item is checked
        counter++;

        // print the duplicate item for reference
        //TODO: figure out how to check for duplicates without knowing the 'Description'
        if (item.containsValue('Cheese')) {
        print(item);
        }

      });

      // return a list of unique descriptions
      final newItems = items.where((item) {
        return set.add(item['Description']);
      }).toList();

      // Print result
      print(newItems);
    }
  }
}

stackDuplicates(items);
```

I cant seem to figure out how to make  a new list with the duplicate quantities combined.
Additionally, I'm trying to check for duplicates without knowing that the value is Cheese; the value could be anything.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

edit: *Sorry I forgot to mention, if the UoM is different, do not stack them.*

Comment: So if number of items have same `Description`, you want to combine them into one summing their `Quantity`, right?

Comment: What about items with same `Description` but different `UoM`?

Comment: Thats exactly right. I'd like to keep the same Description and UoM, but increase the Quantity.

If the UoM is not the same, then it will be considered unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) stack to `Map` where `key` consist of `Description-UoM` fields

2) if such key exists in `Map` simply accumulate `Quantity`

3) return map values as list

```dart
List<dynamic> stackDuplicates(items) {
  Map<String, dynamic> uniqueItems = {};

  for (Map item in items) {
    final key = '${item["Description"]}-${item["UoM"]}';

    (uniqueItems[key] == null)
        ? uniqueItems[key] = item
        : uniqueItems[key]['Quantity'] += item['Quantity'];
  }

  return uniqueItems.values.toList();
}


List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [
  {'Description': 'Cheese', 'Quantity': 100, 'UoM': 'g'},
  {'Description': 'Corn', 'Quantity': 150, 'UoM': 'g'},
  {'Description': 'Cheese', 'Quantity': 52, 'UoM': 'g'},
];

final stackedItems = stackDuplicates(items);
print(stackedItems);
```

feel free to change `key` value depending on grouping rules.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. I am still fairly new to dart, so thank you for explaining it as well.